# Filling box for zoomed plot with a colour in mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I created a plot with zoomed region with following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes,mark_inset


#  random  walk read

random_walk = np.loadtxt("random_walk_for_pict.txt")


if __name__=='__main__':

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,16))
    ax = plt.subplot(111) #whole path
    ax.plot(random_walk)
    ax.set_xlim(0,5000)
    ax.set_ylim(-130,55)

    axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax,2,loc='lower right')
    axins.plot(random_walk)

    x1,x2,y1,y2 = 1000,2000, -60,-15
    axins.set_xlim(x1,x2)
    axins.set_ylim(y1,y2)

    mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3)
    plt.show()
```

based on the documentation from http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#insetlocator and the image is:
 [image: randomwalk]

I would like boxes (zoomed part on bottom left and the smaller box on the main plot) to be filled with light grey color,

but when I write:

```
mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3, fill=True)
```

Which, according to documentation (https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/inset_locator_api.html) should get the job done I get error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "fractal_draw.py", line 39, in  mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3,fill=True)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/inset_locator.py", line 582, in mark_inset
>
> pp = BboxPatch(rect, fill=False, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'fill'

I do no want to create manually another BboxPatch, and I do not know how to override this "fill=False".

How can I get my figure to look the way I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill the inset axes, you may use the `axes_kwargs` argument,

```
zoomed_inset_axes(ax,2,loc='lower right', axes_kwargs={"facecolor" : "lightgray"})
```

Giving the `BboxPatch` of the `mark_inset` is indeed not possible via the arguments to that function. A workaround is to set the required properties after the `BboxPatch` has been created,

```
pp,p1,p2 = mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3)
pp.set_fill(True)
pp.set_facecolor("lightgray")
pp.set_edgecolor("k")
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(43)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes,mark_inset

#  random  walk
random_walk = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(5000))/2-50

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (13,8))
ax = plt.subplot(111) #whole path
ax.plot(random_walk)
ax.set_xlim(0,5000)
ax.set_ylim(-130,55)

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax,2,loc='lower right', 
                          axes_kwargs={"facecolor" : "lightgray"})

axins.plot(random_walk)

x1,x2,y1,y2 = 1000,2000, -60,-15
axins.set_xlim(x1,x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1,y2)

pp,p1,p2 = mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3)
pp.set_fill(True)
pp.set_facecolor("lightgray")
pp.set_edgecolor("k")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

You could also patch the source code. To this end, locate the file `...\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\inset_locator.py` in your python installation. Within this file, find the line (almost at the bottom of file)

```
pp = BboxPatch(rect, fill=False, **kwargs)
```

and replace this line with

```
fill = kwargs.pop("fill", False)
pp = BboxPatch(rect, fill=fill, **kwargs)
```

Once this is done you may create a `mark_inset` as

```
mark_inset(ax,axins,loc1=1,loc2=3, fill=True, edgecolor="k", facecolor="lightgrey")
```

Comment: I did a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9615) for the change in the sourcecode. So from the next release (matplotlib 2.2) on, you will be able to use `mark_inset(..., fill=True)`.